# Is there any event queue for eclipse for compilation events

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to access compilation events in eclipse that shows in error log.
Warning, error etc.
If there is any alternative to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the problems view (where compilation warnings/errors are displayed) as opposed to error log (where system warnings/errors aka stacktraces/bugs in Eclipse are displayed).

The thing that is in the problems view are markers. You can query markers on a resource with code like

```
IResource resource = ...;
IMarker[] markers = resource.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
// iterate over markers to do something interesting
```

More information at [Eclipse's help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm?cp=2_0_10_8) and have a look at the ["Mark My Words"](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html) Eclipse article for an introduction to markers.